# AWS: Help setting up CodeDeploy in a Codepipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy-appspec

It looks like it's impossible to get Codedeploy to work in a CodePipeline project with a CodeBuild.

First I set up a Pipeline with 3 stages: Source, Build and Deploy, the first 2 stages work perfectly but the 3th (CodeDeploy) throws this error:
[image]

CodeBuild pushes the output artifacts to s3 in a .zip file, which is not supported by CodeDeploy.

For this, I tried to set up a Lambda function between CodeBuild and CodeDeploy like this: (Source -> CodeBuild -> Invoke Lambda -> CodeDeploy), The Lambda function uploads the appspec.yml file to s3 and calls putJobSuccessResult, But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

#### BundleType must be either YAML or JSON

There is a known limitation where the deployment of a Lambda using CodePipeline, with CodeDeploy as the Deployment Provider is not supported as of yet.

This is because CodePipeline will always zip the bundle/artifact, whereas CodeDeploy expects a YAML/JSON file as the source (appspec.yaml file) for Lambda Function deployment.

In order to work around this limitation, you have two options:

1. Run AWS CLI commands inside your CodeBuild Stage to update/deploy your lambda function

OR

2. Use CodeBuild to package your lambda function Code and push the artifact to a CloudFormation stage, which will update or create your Lambda Function Resource. You should find the reference documentation at [1] useful for getting the required information about packaging your SAM application.

Ref:

[1] SAM Packaging -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-deploying.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-package-and-deploy

Comment: I used an AWS Lambda as a stage between CodeBuild and CodeDeploy, the lambda doesn't Zip the output artifacts and only upload one file to s3 which is a .yaml, and I still get the same error.

Comment: I noticed your appspec file name is 'appspec.yml' whereas CodeDeploy Lambda deployment requires 'appspec.yaml' - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

Comment: I tried all the these names "appspec.yml", "appSpec.yml", "appspec.yaml" and "appSpec.yaml" and non of them worked, I looks like its not supported to use codebuild and codedeploy together in a pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, It's nothing to do with the filename, it is the zip issue as mentioned in my original answer. "There is a known limitation where the deployment of a Lambda using CodePipeline, with CodeDeploy as the Deployment Provider is not supported as of yet."

Comment: Well, 6 months later and still no solution for this... The first option in this answer worth a shot.